# Why is ZKP authentication not used in practice?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, authentication, anonymity

I have been reading about Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP) protocols for a while now. Among the applications I have seen the most is authentication (https://ethereum.org/en/zero-knowledge-proofs/#authentication). But in practice it is not used; why?

I have also been looking for why these protocols are not used in authentication systems or why they are not used by identity providers (such as Google accounts, Facebook, Microsoft, etc.).

One application I can think of is an identity provider where you don't have to register and log in in the conventional way, but uses ZKP. Would this be viable?

Comment: Viable in which way? We can answer here if it is technically possible or if it has specific requirements that may hinder acceptance. However, please note that asking if it is commercially viable is of course off topic.

Comment: I do not mean commercially viable. I mean technically, for example if it requires a computational capacity that makes it unviable. 
I'm just curious, why isn't it done in practice?